# Is it possible to have comments without blog post in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, comments

I need to have page where people can send comments, but it is not blog post, so is it possible to make comments to that page without making a blog posting?

Comment: You can use a WordPress "page" for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new page, "Comments" ? 
(Use a plugin to exclude this from your main navigation - if needed)

on the page you dont really need to put any text, just scroll down to the "Discussion" section
and make sure to tick the box "Allow Comments"..

then when the page loads you can add comments to it..?
if there is no comment area, then chances are the template file "Page.php" dosnt have the call for the comments file..

just open your page.php file and add

```
<?php comments_template(); ?>
```

were you would like your comment form to appear..